# JQuery UI min and max difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On sliding, I want to display the difference between the max value and current value.
If the difference is 0, fade in the "nodiff" div and display "no diff" text inside (hide "diff div"), otherwise display "diff of [difference value]" in the faded in "diff" div.

2 things.

1) From the `var difference...` line it doesn't seem to function correctly?
2) How can I fade in the divs (see comments below)

My attempt:

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#current" ).html( ui.value );
var min = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "min");
var max = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "max");
var difference = max.value - min.value;
if (difference => 1) $( "#diff").html( "diff of " + difference ); // fade out #nodiff and fade in #diff?
if (difference = 0) $( "#nodiff").html( "no diff" ); // fade out #diff and fade in #nodiff?
}
});
```

Comment: why do you check `ui.value` instead of `difference` directly? Also, `html()` sets the content and does not alter visibility. Either set `html()` on the same element or toggle visibility with `show()/hide()`.

Comment: Updated. still doesn't want to work to display the difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`max`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max) and [`min`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min) options return a numeric value not an object so you have to access the variable `min` or `max` variable directly without the `value` property.

To check the uquality use `==` not `=`.

Like:

```
$("#slider-range-min").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#current").html(ui.value);
        var min = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "min");
        var max = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "max");
        debugger;
        var difference = max - ui.value;
         $("#diff").html('');
        if (difference > 0) $("#diff").html("diff of " + difference); // fade out #nodiff and fade in #diff?
        $("#nodiff").html('');
        if (difference == 0) $("#nodiff").html("no diff"); // fade out #diff and fade in #nodiff?
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LsePU/

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks @Edward. What about fading in the diff/nodiff divs?

Answer (score 1):

1) `(difference = 0)` is an assignment, you want a comparison: `(difference == 0)`

2) min and max are always the same - `0` and `5` thus the difference is always the same: `5`

3) `max` and `min` have no property `.value` - the line should read:

```
var difference = max - min;
```

4) Which values do you want to compare? `min` and `value` or `max` and `value`? Accordingly alter your line:

```
var difference = max - ui.value;
```

html:

```
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>    
<div id="diff"></div>
```

js:
The correct code would be ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qCxnx/)):

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#current" ).html( ui.value );
       var min = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "min");
       var max = $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "max");
       var difference = max - ui.value;
       $( "#diff").html( difference?"diff of " + difference : "no diff" );
    }
});
```

I only use one diff, so you don't need to fade in/out any diffs, just alter the content of the `#diff` div.

Comment: @Dave I modified your code, you only need one div- there is no need for fading. Also feel free to upvote Edward's and my Answer if they helped you. Cheers.